# How does CLR change the capacity of dynamic arrays which instantiated with overloaded constructors?

Tags: c#, .net, list, collections, clr

`.Net` introduced us dynamic arrays like `ArrayList` and `List<T>`. I have always wondered how does `CLR` handle the capacity of dynamic arrays. I have read about that, and now I know that these classes has internal field with the name of `_defaultCapacity`. And when you instantiate the `List<T>` class without specifying the capacity, the initial capacity of the `List<T>` is zero. On the first Add operation to the `List<T>` instance, it will increase the capacity with the default capacity being **four**, which is stored in the internal field `_defaultCapacity` of the `List<T>` class. And  on every expansion of the  `List<T>` class, a new capacity of the `List<T>` will be calculated and it will be two times that of the previous capacity.  But we know that `List<T>` comes to life when we call one of the following three overloaded constructors.

```
public List() {}  // capacity will be: 0, 4, 8, 16, 32 ...
public List(int capacity) {}
public List(IEnumerable<T> collection) {}
```

My question is about how dows CLR increase the capacity of List if we instantiated it with the last two constructors. What if we instantiated it like that:

```
List<T> myList = new List<T>(19);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Add` method will increase the size of the List in the same way, regardless of which constructor is called.

```
public void Add(T item) {
    if (_size == _items.Length) EnsureCapacity(_size + 1);
    _items[_size++] = item;
    _version++;
}

private void EnsureCapacity(int min) {
    if (_items.Length < min) {
        int newCapacity = _items.Length == 0? _defaultCapacity : _items.Length * 2;
        if (newCapacity < min) newCapacity = min;
        Capacity = newCapacity;
    }
}

public int Capacity {
    get { return _items.Length; }
    set {
        if (value != _items.Length) {
            if (value < _size) {
                ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.value, ExceptionResource.ArgumentOutOfRange_SmallCapacity);
            }

            if (value > 0) {
                T[] newItems = new T[value];
                if (_size > 0) {
                    Array.Copy(_items, 0, newItems, 0, _size);
                }
                _items = newItems;
            }
            else {
                _items = _emptyArray;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Source](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/Net/Net/3@5@50727@3053/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/whidbey/netfxsp/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Collections/Generic/List@cs/2/List@cs)

Comment: I thinks it is better to reference the original site with source code http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs